# MpMoviePlayerViewController status bar not hinding when play video

Tags: iphone, ios8, hide, mpmovieplayercontroller, statusbar

I am playing a video in *MpMoviePlayerViewController*. But I am not able to hide status bar of it.

My code is given below

```
mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:_urlToLoad];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

[self presentViewController:mp animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Any one can suggest me what to do in this case.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Same issue here! Did you solve it in the meantime?

Comment: Ah, in my case it was easy: I just needed to remove the following code from my MPMoviePlayerViewController subclass. `- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden { return NO; }` But I guess that doesn't include your problem ...